# How to handle a custom event in a XtraGrid control

Tags: .net, winforms, datagrid, devexpress, xtragrid

I am trying to solve a problem with a DevExpress XtraGrid in a winforms app. I have created a custom RepositoryItemButtonEdit control and have one unbound column in a XtraGrid that uses it. This control is a custom search field which throws an event when it has completed a search.

What I am trying to do is add an event handler to the cell that is running the search so I can get notified when it has completed. Is this possible in a datagrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the following approach:

handle the GridView's ShownEditor event and check the gridView.FocusedColumn property.  If this column's ColumnEdit is set to an instance of your RepositoryItem, the GridView.ActiveEditor property references an instance of your custom editor. Thus, you can subscribe to its events.  Hope, this helps.